# cellForRowAtIndexPath keeps crashing when I attempt to add a new record in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Getting error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance'`...

The `SIGABRT` came on the `else cell.textLabel.text = @"Blank";` line of:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
         cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Pattern" inManagedObjectContext:context];
 // Edit the sort method.
     NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"patternName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
      NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil] autorelease];

     NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
     [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
     [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];    
     _patterns = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
     [fetchRequest release];
     NSArray *names = [_patterns valueForKey:@"patternName"];
     NSArray *urls = [_patterns valueForKey:@"patternUrl"];

     if (names!= nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];           
     }
     else cell.textLabel.text = @"Blank";
     cell.detailTextLabel.text = [urls objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
     cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
     return cell;
 }
```

I can add a defined record (copies the url of the page the user is viewing inserting the URL into both the url field and the name  attributes). Editing or creating a new record pops a ModalViewController that presents (for existing records) and captures data in textfields (for new records). Selecting the save crashes, changes only the record of the last-added defined record even if it has been edited and adds that as a new record, keeping the old one. I think somethings wrong with my keeping track of the number of cells.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: The `for (int i=0; i<[names count]; i++) {` is not necessary and is confusing. You can take the loop out, and leave the if/else in place. Still looking for the bug... (it appears that `cell` isn't initialized, but I don't see it yet...)

Comment: Ok. I've edited that from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get from executeFetchRequest is array of objects not attributes. You need to loop through array of objects and get attributes from each of them

This

```
_patterns = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
     [fetchRequest release];
     NSArray *names = [_patterns valueForKey:@"patternName"];
     NSArray *urls = [_patterns valueForKey:@"patternUrl"];

     if (names!= nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];           
     }
```

Should become

```
_patterns = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
     [fetchRequest release];


     if (names!= nil) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [[_patterns objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"patternName"];           
     }
```

Comment: I had to extend your suggestion to include an `if (urls!=nil)...` conditional. Great work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the problem is actually in the previous line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I think the object returned by [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] is a NSNull.

Try the following:

```
NSString *name = nil;
if (names) {
    name = [names objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (name && name == (id)[NSNull null]) { 
        name = nil;
    }
}
if (!name) {
    name = @"Blank";
}
cell.textLabel.text = name;
```

EDIT: Fixed my logic in the last if statement.

Comment: Would that happen because the NSManagedObject _patterns is missing the data from the ModalViewController?

Comment: To answer your question, I believe that would happen if the field in the table internally is null.

Comment: How can I test for that and if true fix it? suggestions?